# What output for a garbage code generator?

Tags: python, assembly, generator

I'm in a project groupe about analyzing malware at my university and i have to write a programm that generates garbage code like it used to appear in malware to make it harder for reverse engineers analyzing it. 
Now i'm not programming for that long so i got some problems starting it. I decided to write it in python and this is my beginning to get into the language:
    `

```
import random
assem_dic = {1:"mov", 2: "push", 3: "add", 4: "call", 5: "xor", 6: "cmp", 7: 
"jmp", 8: "and", 9: "or"} #Assembler-Commands
var_dic = {"mov": 2, "push": 1, "add": 2, "call": 0, "xor": 2, "cmp": 2, 
"jmp": 0, "and": 2, "or": 2} #Number of Inputs for Commands
gpreg_dic = {1: "eax", 2: "ebx", 3: "ecx", 4: "edx"} #General-Purpose- 
                                                      Register
func_dic = {1: "func()", 2: "func2()", 3: "func3()"}

f=open("garbage.txt", "w+")
f.write("Garbage-Code: \n")
for n in range(10):
    assem = random.randint(1,9)
    print(assem_dic[assem], " ", end="", sep="")   #Picking random command
    f.write(assem_dic[assem]+ " ")
    var = var_dic[assem_dic[assem]]  #Checking how much input the command 
                                      needs
    if(var == 1):
        print(random.randint(0,10))
        f.write(str(random.randint(0,10))+ "\n")
    elif(var == 2):
        print(gpreg_dic[random.randint(1,4)], ",", end="", sep="" )
        f.write(gpreg_dic[random.randint(1,4)]+",")
        print(random.randint(1,10))
        f.write(str(random.randint(1,10))+"\n")
    else:
        print(func_dic[random.randint(1,3)])
        f.write(func_dic[random.randint(1,3)]+"\n")
f.close()
```

`

It just puts out some random assembler commands. 
Now my next step would be to make a programm that generates random data from which the assembler code is shown by IDA Pro(in the example above it doesnt work of course) and then as final step a programm that generates garbage code which lookes like real functions and appears in IDA Pro as functions but with no use, so functions that do nothing, that would have no effect on the main code in which you would put them.

So how do i have to write the programm or what do i have to output that it is shown properly in IDA Pro? Do i need to create opcode? I'm a bit stuck here and don't know how to go on. I hope i was able to explain my problem properly.

Comment: Looks like you need to generate machine code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [`py_to_asm`](https://github.com/Ajax12345/py_to_asm) (disclamer: I wrote the library) to generate `x86-64` assembly with `at&t` syntax.

You can create `assembly` programs by creating an instance of the `py_to_asm.Asm` class with a `contextmanager` or through simple instantiation. By using the `contextmanager`,  a `main` label can be created:

```
import py_to_asm

with py_to_asm.Asm(_label_name = '_main', is_main=True) as asm: #assembly to add two values
   asm.mov(asm.register.EAX, asm.integer(2))
   asm.mov(asm.register.EDX, asm.integer(5))
   asm.add(asm.register.EAX, asm.register.EDX)

print(asm)
```

Output:

```
.data

.text
.globl _main
_main:
  pushq %rbp
  movq %rsp, %rbp
  subq $16, %rsp
  movl $2, %eax
  movl $5, %edx
  addl %edx, %eax
  leave
  ret
```

You can also instantiate the `py_to_asm.Asm` class merely to create variables, registers, and values:

```
_asm = py_to_asm.Asm()
all_registers = _asm.register.__class__.registers
register_storage = _asm.register.EAX.__class__.converter
eax = _asm.register.EAX
edx = _asm.register.EDX
val = _asm.integer(2)
print(all_registers)
print(register_storage)
print(eax, edx, val)
```

Output:

```
['RAX', 'RCX', 'RDX', 'RBX', 'RSP', 'RBP', 'RSI', 'RDI', 'EAX', 'ECX', 'EDX', 'EBX', 'ESP', 'EBP', 'ESI', 'EDI', 'AX', 'CX', 'DX', 'BX', 'SP', 'BP', 'SI', 'DI', 'AH', 'AL', 'CH', 'CL', 'DH', 'DL', 'BH', 'BL']
{'RAX': 64, 'RCX': 64, 'RDX': 64, 'RBX': 64, 'RSP': 64, 'RBP': 64, 'RSI': 64, 'RDI': 64, 'EAX': 32, 'ECX': 32, 'EDX': 32, 'EBX': 32, 'ESP': 32, 'EBP': 32, 'ESI': 32, 'EDI': 32, 'AX': 16, 'CX': 16, 'DX': 16, 'BX': 16, 'SP': 16, 'BP': 16, 'SI': 16, 'DI': 16, 'AH': 8, 'AL': 8, 'CH': 8, 'CL': 8, 'DH': 8, 'DL': 8, 'BH': 8, 'BL': 8}
%eax %edx $2
```

---

To create an executable from the assembly generated, first write the generated contents to a file:

```
with asm.write('garbage_code.s'):
  pass
```

Then, in terminal/command line, run:

```
gcc garbage_code.s -o garbage_executable
```

`garbage_executable` is now the name of the executable file.

Comment: I assume if you omit the label, you'd get only the instructions you asked for, not the useless `subq $16, %rsp` or the RBP stack-frame setup/teardown, or the `ret`?  The OP is asking about making instruction sequences for shellcode.  Anyway, why is it reserving 16 bytes of stack space in a function that doesn't touch memory (other than the `ret` itself, and the saved RBP)

Comment: Ty for youre answer. The output of my programm should be a .exe file which i can put in a programm like IDA Pro, how can i do that now? Because i need the assembly output to be shown in that programm. So how cann i add the assembly output to a .exe file?